# How to send data to a PHP script and by using the jQuery AJAX load() instruction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to commit the string `"123456"` to the `aaa.php` script with the jQuery `load()` function. The general syntax of the load() function looks like this:

```
$(selector).load(url,data,function(response,status,xhr))
```

In my case I use the function in the following way

```
$("#htmlElement").load("scripts/aaa.php",'123456');
```

How can I get access to the string `"123456"` inside the following php script?

```
<?php
  $input; //this should be the string "123456"
  //some calculations
  echo result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `.load()` to send data you would have to enclose the data properly:

```
 $("#htmlElement").load("scripts/aaa.php",{data:'123456'});
```

Once done the value will be available in the POST array:

```
$input = $_POST['data']; // will be 123456
```

Answer (score 1):

In Js:

```
$("#htmlElement").load("scripts/aaa.php",{data:'123456'});
```

In php you can access a post string like below:

```
$input = $_POST['data'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign '123456' to an element, and then call it back in the php e.g.

```
$( "#new-projects" ).load( "/resources/load.html #projects li" );
```

Have a read of this, it explained the load function perfectly allowing you to find your answer - http://api.jquery.com/load/